# Launch Android emulator on console (without graphic desktop )

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run android emulator on terminal I have downloaded android sdk on VM ubuntu server (Thus I dont have graphic desktop, only terminal console).

I want to run emulator on terminal as a service that I can use for install App and run some tests(battery consumption, install, others).
I want to create some AVD and run test scripts on it.

But, I cant launch emulator without graphic desktop. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find that it's possible start Android Emulator without graphic with this command:

```
$emulator -avd <avd_name> -no-window
```

Also you can add other commands to clean data on emulator

```
$emulator -avd <avd_name> -no-window -wipe-data
```